# How do i add an "(if)" that allows only letters between a-f || A-F?

Tags: c, char, hex, decimal, scanf

I wrote a program that does conversion from hex to decimal. all I got left is to check if the `char` is between `a`-`f` or `A`-`F`, maybe `0`-`9` as well. if it is not between them it will print `"Illegal input"`.

My code:

```
int n, i;
char currentDigit;
unsigned long int sum, currentDigitInt;

printf("Enter the number of digits in the Hexadecimal number:");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
sum = 0;

printf("Enter the Hexadecimal number:\n");
for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    scanf_s(" %c", &currentDigit);

    if (currentDigit >= 'a') {
        currentDigitInt = (currentDigit - 'a') + 10;
    }
    else if (currentDigit >= 'A') {
        currentDigitInt = (currentDigit - 'A') + 10;
    }
    else
        currentDigitInt = currentDigit - '0';
    sum += currentDigitInt * pow(16, i);
}

printf("The decimal number is: %u", sum);
```

The output I need:

```
Enter the number of digits in the Hexadecimal number: 2
Enter the Hexadecimal number: QQ
Illegal input
```

Comment: You may want to use `isxdigit(currentDigit)`.

Comment: something like `(currentDigit >= 'a' && currentDigit <= 'f')` ?

Comment: Did not `scanf_s(" %c", &currentDigit);` generate a warning?  What compiler and warning options are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you can test character ranges with the `&&` operator. For example:

  ```
  if (currentDigit >= 'a' && currentDigit <= 'f')
  ```
- you combine these tests in a series of `if` / `else` and complain if none of the tests match.
- note also that the expression for `sum` is incorrect too. `sum += currentDigitInt * pow(16, i);` should be;

  ```
  sum = sum * 16 + currentDigitInt;
  ```
- the `printf` format for `unsigned long` is `%lu`, not `%u`.
- you should test the return value of `scanf_s` to properly detect a potential end of file.
- `scanf_s` expects 2 extra arguments for conversion specifier `%c` and may not be available on all systems.
- note too that you do not need to ask for the number of hex digits, just break from the loop when the character entered is a newline for the second time.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int currentDigit;
    unsigned long int sum;
    int invalid = 0;

    printf("Enter the Hexadecimal number: ");
    sum = 0;
    while ((currentDigit = getchar()) ! EOF && currentDigit != '\n') {
        int currentDigitInt;
        if (currentDigit >= 'a' && currentDigit <= 'f') {
            currentDigitInt = (currentDigit - 'a') + 10;
        } else
        if (currentDigit >= 'A' && currentDigit <= 'F') {
            currentDigitInt = (currentDigit - 'A') + 10;
        } else
        if (currentDigit >= '0' && currentDigit <= '9') {
            currentDigitInt = currentDigit - '0';
        } else {
            invalid = 1;
            continue;     // keep scanning the input until end of line
        }
        sum = sum * 16 + currentDigitInt;
    }
    if (invalid) {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
    } else {
        printf("The decimal number is: %lu\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- The C standard does guarantee that `0` through `9` are consecutive but purists will argue that the letters `a` through `f` and `A` through `F` might not be consecutive the execution character set. While the are correct, obscuring newbie programmers with these considerations is counter productive and quite excessive as these character ranges are consecutive in both ASCII and EBCDIC (the gaps in EBCDIC are between `i` and `j` and between `r` and `s` in both cases).

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", &currentDigit)` looks wrong. Perhaps `scanf_s("%c", &currentDigit, 1)`?

Comment: @chux: good point, but `1` should be `(rsize_t)1`, which may have a different type from `1U`. I updated the code with a more portable approach.

Comment: Good improvement with  `fgetc()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the code.

For starters the function `scanf_s` shall include as a parameter the size of buffer for the format specifier `c`.

To output an object of the type `unsigned long` you have to use the format specifier `ul`.

In these if statements you do not check the upper limit of valid alpha hexadecimal digits.

```
if (currentDigit >= 'a') {
    currentDigitInt = (currentDigit - 'a') + 10;
}
else if (currentDigit >= 'A') {
    currentDigitInt = (currentDigit - 'A') + 10;
}
```

To check whether an entered symbol is a valid hex digit you should write a separate function.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done.

```
//Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64

#include  <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int hex_digit( char c )
{
    const char *alpha = "ABCDEF";

    unsigned char c1 = toupper( ( unsigned char )c );
    const char *p;

    int result = -1;

    if ( '0' <= c1 && c1 <= '9' )
    {
        result = c1 - '0';
    }
    else if ( c1 != '\0' && ( p = strchr( alpha, c1 ) ) != NULL )
    {
        result = *p - alpha[0] + 10;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    const unsigned long HEX_BASE = 16;
    unsigned int n;

    printf( "Enter the number of digits in the Hexadecimal number: " );
    scanf_s("%u", &n); 

    unsigned long sum = 0;

    if ( n )
    {            
        printf( "Enter the Hexadecimal number: " );

        unsigned int i = 0;
        for ( ; i < n; i++ )
        {
            char c;

            scanf_s( " %c", &c, 1 );

            int digit = hex_digit( c );

            if ( digit < 0 ) break;
            else sum = sum * HEX_BASE + digit; 
        }

        if ( i == n )
        {
            printf("The decimal number is: %ul\n", sum);
        }
        else
        {
            puts( "Illegal input" );
        }    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look the following way

```
Enter the number of digits in the Hexadecimal number: 8
Enter the Hexadecimal number: ffFFffFF
The decimal number is: 4294967295l
```

If you want you can add a check in the program that the specifird number of inputted hexadecimal digits is not greater than `2 * sizeof( unsigned long )`.

Comment: Interesting that if  a _null character_ is read with `scanf_s( " %c", &c, 1 );`, `hex_digit( c );` returns -55.

Comment: @chux Though it works as expected nevertheless I added addition condition c1 != '\0' in the corresponding if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int isaTof(int c)
{
    c = toupper(c);

    if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return 1;
    return 0;
}


int isin(int c, const char *allowedchars)
{
    return strchr(allowedchars, c) != NULL;
}

int isHEXNumber(const char *number)
{
    const char allowedchars[] = "abcdefABCDEF0123456789";
    while(*number)
    {
        if(!isin(*number++, allowedchars)) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

or nitpickers version

```
int isHEXNumber(const char *number)
{
    const char allowedchars[] = "abcdefABCDEF0123456789";

    if(!number || |*number) return 0;
    while(*number)
    {
        if(!isin(*number++, allowedchars)) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}



int main()
{
    const char allowedchars[] = "abcdefABCDEF0123456789";

    printf("%s\n", isin('d', allowedchars) ? "Yes" : "No");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `printf("%s\n", isin('\0', allowedchars) ? "Yes" : "No");` prints "Yes".  But then that is not an issue for `isHEXNumber()`.

Comment: it is up to the user the check this trivial cases. Also the NULL pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`a` (`A`) to `f` (`F`) need not be consecutive in C.

If you want your program to run on all implementations of C (klingon space-ship, [DS9K](http://statemaster.com/encyclopedia/DeathStation-9000), Mars Rover, ..., ...) you could try something like this

```
if ((currentdigit == 0) || (strchr("0123456789abcdefABCDEF", currentdigit) == NULL)) /* invalid */;
```

Comment: This approach is not perfect either since `currentDigit = '\0'` will match although if is not a hex digit.